# Resample v.s. Reduce Resolution in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, resampling

When upscaling an image, Google Earth Engine provides two methods, [Resampling and Reducing Resolution](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/resample). I was wondering which one should I choose.

Take MODIS LAI data for an example, if I want to increase the scale of images from the original 500m to 2500m, I compare the result of bilinear resampling and reduceResolution by mean.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD15A2H')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-10-01')
                  .select('Lai_500m');

var image = collection.first();

var crs_new = image.projection().crs();
var scale_new = image.projection().nominalScale().multiply(5);

var resampled_image = image.resample('bilinear')
                .reproject({crs: crs_new, scale: scale_new});

var reduce_resolution_image = image
                      .reduceResolution({
                        reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                        maxPixels: 65536})
                      .reproject({crs: crs_new, scale: scale_new});

var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'df923d', 'f1b555', 'fcd163', '99b718', '74a901',
    '66a000', '529400', '3e8601', '207401', '056201', '004c00', '023b01',
    '012e01', '011d01', '011301'],
};

Map.addLayer(image, colorizedVis, 'original image');
Map.addLayer(resampled_image, colorizedVis, 'resampled image');
Map.addLayer(reduce_resolution_image, colorizedVis, 'reduce resolution image');
Map.setCenter(-100, 37, 10);
```

The results of the two methods differ when comparing the pixel-level value at 2500m. It should be different since they are different methods. However, what confused me is that the result of bilinear resampling is always integers, the same as the original data (before applying the scale factor 0.1).

Thus, I was wondering:

1. What is the algorithm behind the bilinear resample method? If it is an interpolation method, I guess the result should not always be integer. Does it just use the result of the pre-stored pyramid image, which is sampled from the original pixels at 500m? If so, does reduceResolution calculate the statistics at the native scale (500m) or also use the pyramid images?
2. Since these two methods are different, which method should I choose when upscaling an image? Resample is always faster and does not have maxPixels limit. But I am not sure whether it is accurate.